# Strange interaction between popen() and printf vs. cout in C++

Tags: c++, printf, popen, cout

It's probably a long-shot that anyone can answer this without seeing all the source code and libraries, etc., but I'll try.

I have a program `X` written in C++ using boost-1.41.  If `X` outputs with `std::cout`, then running `X` from another program using `fp=popen("X", "r")` allows `X`'s output to be seen via `fgets(buff, 1024, fp)`.

Now if I change `X` to use `printf()` instead of `std::cout`, the output of `X` is no longer seen.  However, running `X` from bash produces the output as expected.

What could possibly explain this difference?!  I suspect boost is involved here, but I don't know much about boost.

**Note:** I am happy sticking to `std::cout` and my problem is solved.  But I'm trying to understand what the problem was with `printf()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that you probably used `std::endl` with `std::cout`. That, in addition to writing a newline character, also flushes the output buffer.

To do the same with `printf` you can just add `fflush(stdout);` after the call.

Comment: Nicely done; that was it.  I had no idea std::endl flushed buffers.

Comment: They both also periodically flush themselves, but at largely unpredictable intervals.

Comment: @Fixee: Yes, that's why `std::cout << std::endl` is MUCH slower than `std::cout << '\n'`

Comment: That's what `std::endl` is for.  It's usually better just to use `'\n'` or `"\n"` and let the system decided when to flush its buffers.

Comment: Thanks; here the flush was critical because (apparently) writing to a pipe auto-flushes much less often than writing to a term device, which had me perplexed.